# C++ member initialization

Tags: c++

Below is the code where I'm learning the concepts of copy constructor and assignment operator. I'm referring the Bjarne Stroustrup C++11 book. But my program is crashing during when Vector class objects go out of scope. Here is the code I've written.

```
#include <iostream>


class Vector {
    double* elements;
    size_t size;
    
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(const Vector& vec);
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& vec);
    
    ~Vector();
    
    void print() {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            std::cout << elements[i] << ", ";
            
        std::cout << "\b\b \b" << std::endl;
    }
};

Vector::Vector() {
    size = 10;
    elements = new double[size];
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        elements[i] = i + 1;
}

Vector::~Vector() {
    if(elements != nullptr)
        delete[] elements;
}

Vector::Vector(const Vector& vec) : elements { new double[size] }, size { vec.size } {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        elements[i] = vec.elements[i];
}

Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& vec) {
    size = vec.size;
    if(elements != nullptr)
        delete[] elements;
        
    elements = new double[size];
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        elements[i] = vec.elements[i];  
}

int32_t main(int32_t argc, char* argv[]) {
    Vector vec1;
    std::cout << "vec1 elements are: " << std::endl;
    vec1.print();
    
    Vector vec2 = vec1;
    std::cout << "vec2 elements are: " << std::endl;
    vec2.print();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your copy constructor allocates `size` elements before `size` is initialized.  That's probably not your root cause, but it's definitely a bug.  Try running your program with valgrind, or build with asan turned on.

Comment: `Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& vec)` has undefined behavior. It promises to return a Vector& but does not return anything.

Comment: @drescherjm I was supposed to return *this, but anyhow right now I'm not doing any operation where assignment operator overloaded function gets called.

Comment: When I read the code on a question I usually look for as many bugs as I see in the code usually in the first minute even if the bug is not the one causing the behavior in reported in the question. The bug @StephenNewell mentioned probably causes the crash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues in your code. First, in the constructor, you are using the current `size` member to allocate memory. Since it's uninitialized, this invokes undefined behavior. You should use the `vec.size` to allocate memory:

```
Vector::Vector(const Vector& vec) : elements { new double[vec.size] }, size { vec.size } {
                                                      //  ^^^   
  // ...
}
```

Second, you are not returning from `operator=` which also invokes undefined behavior.

```
Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& vec) {
     // ... 
    return *this;  // you need to return
}
```

If you simply turn on all possible warnings, the compiler will tell you about these issues.

Comment: In the book the example program is written in this syntax which I just copied. Thanks for answering the right way to do it.

Comment: @Harry `Stroustrup` has an errata online for errors in his books.

Comment: @drescherjm I can't imagine obvious bugs like this actually being from the book. Maybe he copied a example thats supposed to point out a mistake instead of being working code.